# Javascript WebSocket WSS and PHP Socket

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to make a small app using PHP Socket using HTTPS ans WSS javascript Socket 
This is my PHP Code

On my client server i'm already on https but using an IP Address

This is the PHP server side

```
<?php

$ip="my-server-url.com";               //Set the TCP IP Address to listen on
$port="8099";                  //Set the TCP Port to listen on
$pem_passphrase = "12345";   //Set a password here
$pem_file = "filename.pem";    //Set a path/filename for the PEM SSL Certificate which will be created.

//The following array of data is needed to generate the SSL Cert
$pem_dn = array(
    "countryName" => "UK",                 //Set your country name
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "SPN",      //Set your state or province name
    "localityName" => "LN",        //Ser your city name
    "organizationName" => "CN",  //Set your company name
    "organizationalUnitName" => "OUN", //Set your department name
    "commonName" => "CM",  //Set your full hostname.
    "emailAddress" => "email@example.com"  //Set your email address
);

//create ssl cert for this scripts life.
echo "Creating SSL Cert\n";
createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn);

//setup and listen to a tcp IP/port, returning the socket stream
echo "Listening to {$ip}:{$port} for connections\n";
$socket = setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port);

//enter a loop until an exit command is received.
$exit=false;
$i=1;
while($exit==false) {

    //Accept any new connections
    $forkedSocket = stream_socket_accept($socket, "-1", $remoteIp);

    echo "New connection from $remoteIp\n";

    //start SSL on the connection
    stream_set_blocking ($forkedSocket, true); // block the connection until SSL is done.
    stream_socket_enable_crypto($forkedSocket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_SERVER);

    //Read the command from the client. This will read 8192 bytes of data, If you need to read more you may need to increase this. However some systems will fragment the command over 8192 anyway, so you would instead need to write a loop waiting for the command input to end before proceeding.
    $command = fread($forkedSocket, 8192);

    //unblock connection
    stream_set_blocking ($forkedSocket, false);

    //run a switch on the command to determine what we need to do
    switch($command) {
        //exit command will cause this script to quit out
        CASE "exit";
            $exit=true;
            echo "exit command received \n";
            break;

        //hi command
        CASE "hi";
            //write back to the client a response.
            fwrite($forkedSocket, "Hello {$remoteIp}. This is our $i command run!");
            $i++;

            echo "hi command received \n";
            break;
    }

    //close the connection to the client
    fclose($forkedSocket);
}
exit(0);



function createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn) {
//create ssl cert for this scripts life.

    //Create private key
    $privkey = openssl_pkey_new();

    //Create and sign CSR
    $cert    = openssl_csr_new($pem_dn, $privkey);
    $cert    = openssl_csr_sign($cert, null, $privkey, 365);

    //Generate PEM file
    $pem = array();
    openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem[0]);
    openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pem[1], $pem_passphrase);
    $pem = implode($pem);

    //Save PEM file
    file_put_contents($pem_file, $pem);
    chmod($pem_file, 0600);
}

function setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port) {
//setup and listen to a tcp IP/port, returning the socket stream

    //create a stream context for our SSL settings
    $context = stream_context_create();

    //Setup the SSL Options
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem_file);  // Our SSL Cert in PEM format
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pem_passphrase); // Private key Password
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

    //create a stream socket on IP:Port
    $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
    stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, false);

    return $socket;
}
?>
```

and this is my Javascript code client side

```
<script>    
    var socket = new WebSocket('wss://my-server-url.com:8099');
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    };
</script>
```

using navigator i'm trying to reach my PHP Socket server but i'm getting this error
Console error

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-server-url.com:8099/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

The error from my server PHP Socket app

```
New connection from xx.xx.xx.xx:60465
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number in /usr/local/socketphp/sslapp.php on line 45
```

But using telnet from my machine directly it works !

Comment: did you found a solution ?